# Description number as Section.Number

Tags: enumerate, context

I have this [description](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupdescriptions):

```
\defineenumeration
  [exercici]
  [alternative=serried,text={Exercici},stopper={.\space},width=fit]
```

I want to put something like this

```
Exercici 1.1. Bla
```

when I type:

```
\startexercici Bla
\stopexercici
```

where the first 1 is the number of the section (instead of `Exercici 1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
%\setuppapersize[A6]
\defineenumeration[exercici]
    [alternative=serried,
     prefix=yes,
     prefixsegments=section,
     way=bysection, %comment it so that the enumeration counter isn't reset
     text={Exercici},stopper={.\space},
     width=fit]
\starttext
\startsection[title=nice]
\startexercici This
\stopexercici
\startexercici isn't
\stopexercici
\stopsection
\startsection[title=nice]
\startexercici an
\stopexercici
\startexercici example
\stopexercici
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Jairo: it works even if there is no section at all: it prints `Exercici 1` if there is no section instead of annoying `Exercici 0.1`